# Find if an ipa file is 32 or 64-bit. (macos/unix)

Tags: ios, macos, unix, x86-64, ipa

We have multiple archives in our build location. Is there a way to identify if it is 32 or 64-bit based. So that I can group them accordingly.

I tried `file` command. but it didn't give the info I look for.

```
MYMAC:~ userid$ file MyApp.ipa
MyApp.ipa: Zip archive data, at least v1.0 to extract
```

I searched internet for this and I couldn't find one. Can someone please point me in right direction ?

We have a repo at unix as well. Atlas, if I am able to identify in Mac , I can sync it up with unix's list.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20104403/determine-if-ios-device-is-32-or-64-bit

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik thanks, but I just have the .ipa file, that question is to find inside the app?

Comment: oh u have only ipa, u need w/o Xcode u need find the version

Comment: the reason you couldn't find an answer online is because ipa is essentially a zipped up file. the only way you will know if its 32 vs 64 bit is by unzipping its content. There is no other quick way to check.

Comment: @SamB ok, and after unzipping the content, how do you determine if the `.ipa` file has been compiled for `32-bit` only or for both `32-bit` and `64-bit`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

First, try unzip the ipa  file to a directory, eg:

```
unzip <filename>.ipa -d ~/Downloads/tmp
```

Second, use file command to identify the architectures, eg:

```
file ~/Downloads/tmp/Payload/<appname>.app/<app>
```

Then, you will have what you want~

```
~/Downloads/tmp/Payload/<appname>.app/<app>: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
~/Downloads/tmp/Payload/<appname>.app/<app> (for architecture armv7):  Mach-O executable arm
~/Downloads/tmp/Payload/<appname>.app/<app> (for architecture cputype (16777228) cpusubtype (0)):      Mach-O 64-bit executable
```